# Load php.ini in each folder

Tags: apache-2.2, php, php.ini

I have a question for the php.ini in root folder, how it can be loaded when reading the page and overwrite the original value.

When I was using the webhosting service, I could simply put the php.ini into root folder, then file will overwrite the existing php.ini value on the original php.ini.

However, I am now trying to use local server for development. I use OSX Server App to setup a server, upgraded php5.4 to 5.5 and check everything is good. The phpinfo function shows nothing wrong. But when I put another php.ini in each folder of developing website, they are not be loaded when page is loading. (Its working if I change the value on original php.ini).

May I ask what I am missing and what should I looking for??

Thank you very much for your help!!

Best regards,

Comment: Apache1 or Apache2?

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen Apache2

Answer (score 0):

There will be a difference if you are using `mod_php` or `suPHP`. It's likely that you'll be running `mod_php`, whereas your host will be running `suPHP` (`suPHP` comes with the advantage that scripts run as the correct user, not as a general user like `nobody` which is what `mod_php` does).

The feature you're looking for, custom `php.ini` files, is something specific to `suPHP`. So, there are two solutions to your scenario:

1. Run `suPHP` on your local machine
2. Change the relevant settings in either `php.ini` or in `.htaccess` via things like `php_flag`

Personally, I'd recommend running your local setup as close to production as possible; so I'd opt for option one.